# The derivative of a non-tempered distribution can be tempered?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Suppose we have a non- tempered distribution $u\in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R^d)\backslash \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^d)$. Is it possible to have $\partial_{x_1}...\partial_{x_d}u \in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^d)$ where the derivative is taken in the sense of Schwartz distributions? I cannot find an example nor prove the converse. Any reference to suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^x+e^y$ defines an obviously non tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$, whose *mixed* derivative $\partial_x\partial_y(e^x+e^y)=0$ ...

Answer (score 4):

A distribution is tempered if and only if it is the distributional derivative $D^nF$ of a continuous function $F$ which is $O(x^k)$ for some positive integer.  Its primitive is then $D^{n-1}F$ and so also tempered.  Hence the answer to your question is no. (Suitable reference: J. Sebastiao e Silva, Integrals and orders of growth of distributions, Lisbon, 1964).

Edit. I wrote up the one-dimensional case dor simplicity.  If $n=0$, you have a continous function and you simply take its classical primitive which is clearly a tempered distribution.

Comment: I agree that there is a structure theorem for tempered distributions. In fact $u=\partial^\alpha ((1+|x|^2)^n f(x))$ for some continuous and bounded function $f$ and multi-indexe $\alpha$ and integer $n$. The problem is if $\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_d)$ is such that $\alpha_i=0$ for some $i$: then taking the derivative of a lower order makes no sense.

Comment: I have a concern: that tells me that for any tempered distribution $T$, there is a tempered distribution solution to $\partial x_1...\partial x_d u=T$. In dimension $1$ the only primitives of $0$ are constants so in fact any solution of this equation is tempered. But what about in higher dimension? The solutions to $\partial x_1...\partial x_d u=0$ have support in the union of the axes of $\mathbb R^d$ but is there more?